# PM2 using different user name in aws linux ec2 instance using node js typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, amazon-ec2, pm2, cicd

I'm using **Linux EC2 instance** in AWS using node js project typescript. I have created the pipeline only for **Source** and **deployment**.
For that, I created the **appspec.yml** file and **ecosystem.config.js file**. In the appspec.yml file, I have created **after_install.sh** and **application_start.sh** scripts. I have used **pm2** in that node js project.
If I change and push the code to code commit, the pipeline triggers automatically pull the code and deploy, at that time the after_install and application_start files are run, and all are working fine but the pm2 is not restarted. If I manually do that, it works.
It didn't work in the CICD but all the logs are printed in the deploy.log file, I mean echo strings and it didn't throw the errors.

If i run the command **pm2 restart** manually it shows the user name is **ec2-user** in the deploy.log, if I run the **pm2 restart** in the script files (after_install.sh and application_start.sh) , It retuns the user name is **root**

**appspec.yml**

```
version: 0.0
os: linux
files:
  - source: /
    destination: /home/ec2-user/nodejsProject
hooks:
  AfterInstall:
    - location: scripts/after_install.sh
      timeout: 300
      runas: root
  ApplicationStart:
    - location: scripts/application_start.sh
      timeout: 300
      runas: root
```

**after_install.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

# Log the script execution
echo 'Run after_install.sh: ' >> /home/ec2-user/nodejsProject/deploy.log

# Change directory
echo 'cd /home/ec2-user/nodejsProject' >> /home/ec2-user/nodejsProject/deploy.log
cd /home/ec2-user/nodejsProject >> /home/ec2-user/nodejsProject/deploy.log

# Source nvm
source /home/ec2-user/.nvm/nvm.sh

# Log the current PATH for troubleshooting
echo "PATH is: $PATH" >> /home/ec2-user/nodejsProject/deploy.log

# Install npm dependencies
echo 'npm install' >> /home/ec2-user/nodejsProject/deploy.log 
/home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v16.20.2/bin/npm install >> /home/ec2-user/nodejsProject/deploy.log

# Start the application with pm2
echo 'pm2 start' >> /home/ec2-user/nodejsProject/deploy.log 
/home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v16.20.2/bin/pm2 start /home/ec2-user/nodejsProject/ecosystem.config.js --update-env >> /home/ec2-user/nodejsProject/deploy.log

# Save the pm2 process list
echo 'pm2 save' >> /home/ec2-user/nodejsProject/deploy.log 
/home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v16.20.2/bin/pm2 save >> /home/ec2-user/nodejsProject/deploy.log

# Setup pm2 startup
echo 'pm2 startup' >> /home/ec2-user/nodejsProject/deploy.log 
/home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v16.20.2/bin/pm2 startup >> /home/ec2-user/nodejsProject/deploy.log

echo 'After_install completed' >> /home/ec2-user/nodejsProject/deploy.log
```

**application_start.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

echo 'Run application_start.sh: ' >> /home/ec2-user/nodejsProject/deploy.log
source /home/ec2-user/.nvm/nvm.sh

# Change directory
echo 'cd /home/ec2-user/nodejsProject' >> /home/ec2-user/nodejsProject/deploy.log
cd /home/ec2-user/nodejsProject >> /home/ec2-user/nodejsProject/deploy.log

# Restart the application with pm2
echo 'pm2 restart' >> /home/ec2-user/nodejsProject/deploy.log
/home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v16.20.2/bin/pm2 restart /home/ec2-user/nodejsProject/ecosystem.config.js --update-env >> /home/ec2-user/nodejsProject/deploy.log

echo 'Finished application_start.sh: ' >> /home/ec2-user/nodejsProject/deploy.log
```

ecosystem.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    apps: [
      {
        name: 'nodejsProject',
        script: './app/app.ts',
        interpreter: './node_modules/.bin/ts-node',

      },
    ],
};
```